# Array of pointers to pointers delete error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Ok so i got the functions addCar,Copy_Arr and free_A. I bassicly want add to dynamic array *int **CarArray* everytime new int *carNum to point to,so i have to use temporary array to do so.
The Program keeps getting stuck at the free_A function and i don't understend why.

```
 void main()
    {
        int **CarArray=NULL;
        int *carNum = NULL;
        int *numOfCars;
        numOfCars=(int)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *numOfCars = 0;
        addCar(CarArray,carNum,numOfCars);
    }

    int **addCar(int **CarArray, int *carNum, int *numOfCars)
    {
        int i,size;
        int** temp=NULL;
        temp=Build_A(temp,*numOfCars + 1);//function for memory allocation
        carNum=buildNumber();
        temp[*numOfCars] = carNum;
        Copy_Arr(CarArray, temp,*numOfCars);
        free_A(CarArray, *numOfCars);
        *numOfCars = *numOfCars + 1;
        CarArray=Build_A(CarArray, *numOfCars);
        Copy_Arr(temp, CarArray, *numOfCars);
        free_A(temp, *numOfCars);
        return CarArray;


    }


    void Copy_Arr(int **From, int **To, int  numOfCars)
    {
        int i,j,size = 0;
        for (j = 0;j < numOfCars;j++)
        {
            size = From[j][0];
            for (i = 0;i <size+1;i++)
            {
                To[j][i] = From[j][i];
            }
        }
    }


    void free_A(int **Arr, int num)
    {
        int i;
            for (i = 0;i < num;i++)
            {
                free(Arr[i]);
            }

        free(Arr);
    }

    int** Build_A(int **Arr, int num)
    {
        Arr = (int **)malloc((num) * sizeof(int*));
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0;i < num;i++)
        {
            Arr[i] = (int*)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
        }
        return Arr;
    }

int *buildNumber()
{
    int i,num;
    int size;
    int* arr=NULL;
    printf("Please Enter Plate Size\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Please Enter Plate Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    arr = (int*)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(int));
    for (i = size;i > 0;i--)
    {
        arr[i] = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }

    arr[0] = size;
    printarr(arr);

    return arr;


}
```

Comment: Could you also include `Build_A`?

Comment: And show how you call all of the above functions, or best show a [mcve].

Comment: i Added void main and Build_A

Comment: Not directly related, but  `numOfCars = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));` is pointless. Is there a specific reason why you are dynamically allocating  a single `int`?. And anyway it should be at least `numOfCars = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` or even better `numOfCars = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: Ok i'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem should be in line 18:

```
Copy_Arr(CarArray, temp,*numOfCars);
```

because 'CarArray' is NULL at this point. So in line 35:

```
size = From[j][0];
```

It should be an error.

Comment: when CarArray is null *numOfCars is 0 so it won't even enter the loop. i debugged it and it throws exeption after i try to free **temp or **carArray

Comment: @Okr100 what is `buildNumber`? The problem may be there (no joke). Show a [mcve].

Comment: @MichaelWalz Added buildNumber.it is just function to build an array of numbers.

Comment: @Okr100 OK, now maybe we can help. The `BuildNumber` function could just have a subtle bug that has dramatic consequences later on. And it also helps us to construct a [MCVE] (which BTW _you_  are supposed to provide).